# Initialize LocalServerSocket with SOCKET_SEQPACKET socket type

Tags: java, android, localsocket, localserversocket

Is there a way to initialize an android [LocalServerSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalServerSocket.html) with [SOCKET_SEQPACKET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html#SOCKET_SEQPACKET) type to avoid handling packet boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, LocalServerSocket has constructor that gets a file descriptor. Initialize a LocalSocket with LocalSocket.SOCKET_SEQPACKET, bind it to LocalSocketAddress and pass its file descriptor to the LocalServerSocket constructor.